# Page Isn't Working Error - Laravel cPanel

Tags: cpanel

I am trying to upload my laravel project to cPanel.

I have uploaded the contents of the public folder in Laravel to the public_html directory

I have uploaded the rest of the laravel files to a folder called 'project'

I have changed the index.php file like this.

```
 require __DIR__.'/../project/vendor/autoload.php';
 $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../project/bootstrap/app.php';
```

I am getting an error "Page isn't working HTTP ERROR 500"

The Project folder directory is /project
and the public folder contents are in /public_html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you look up the actual error in your log files? This could be anything.

Comment: 500 indicates that there's an error, this might be literally anything
in cpanel you should have error logs, share with us the latest entries so we can help debug

Comment: the error log seems to be empty. Metrics->errors is empty. Should I enable error logging somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I had to change the php version which was defaulted to 5.4 to 7.2 and that did the trick and everything works perfectly now.